# How can I modify my plugin to work with hoverIntent if it is available?

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I hav a plugin that uses [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) but it should use [`hoverIntent()`](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) if it is available.

How would I do this with minimum fuss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will detect if hoverIntent has been included, and modify the `hover` method to `hoverIntent` in that case.

```
var bindMethod = $.isFunction(jQuery().hoverIntent) ? 'hoverIntent' : 'hover';

element[bindMethod](
function() {
  // Mouse over
},
function() {
  // Mouse out
});
```

You can then leave a note with your plugin that says...

> - Compatible with [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).